# Is it possible to reverse a doubly circular linked list? if Yes, then how?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am a bit confused, as one of my friend said it not possible. As it's totally symmetric.

I have googled a bit but I am still confused

Comment: Yes, you can swap the head and the tail pointer, and all next and previous pointers of the nodes. As long as you do proper bookkeeping, that will work.

Comment: Your friend is correct. Given that the list is circular, and you have the ability to traverse the list in the clockwise direction and the counterclockwise direction, reversing the list doesn't change any useful properties of the list.

Comment: @user3386109: it is not useful, but that does not imply it is not possible :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It all comes down to semantics. For example, if you look at  Daniel's drawing, and remove the words, then there is absolutely no difference between the three lists. So was there really any change?

Comment: @user3386109: as a former AI researcher, I think a scientist would say that the two are *isomoprhic*. I'm afraid that is probably the strongest claim one can make :) After all we have labeled two nodes: the *head* and *tail*, and after the transformation, the head and the tail are no longer the same. Furthermore for *n=3* there is a special case, but for *n>3*, in fact the next of a node has not per se the same value.

Comment: The interest of isomorphisms lies in the fact that two isomorphic objects cannot be distinguished by using only the properties used to define morphisms; thus **isomorphic objects may be considered the same** as long as one considers only these properties and their consequences. Emphasis added ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You (and those that have answered) have labelled two nodes `head` and `tail`. Those labels are not necessary, and are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @user3386109: sure, but then you consider *next* and *previous* to have no information at all? So `1->2->3->4->1` (cycle) is the same as `1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 1` (cycle)? A tour from the New York to San Franciso to Vermont for example, is not the same as a tour in the opposite direction.

Comment: @user3386109: well besides that there is a next and a previous. That's not necessary as well?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem As I already said, it all comes down to semantics. You have chosen to give the edges semantic meaning by calling them `next` and `previous`. They could just as well be called `a` and `b`.

Comment: @user3386109: evidently isomorphic objects can be considered equal if you remove the "destinguishing" parts away. After all, what we can do is make a *projection* on the properties that span the isomorphism. But I think a lot of category theorists would not eat it :P Especially since for example a *catamorphism*, etc. are defined to take advantage of that. In computing (like the Hask category), a catamorphism is usually one of the workhorses of transforming data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly, I believe that was the point the friend was trying to make. Remove the distinguishing features (i.e. the labels on the edges), and view the circular list simply as a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). There is nothing to reverse because the graph is totally symmetric.

Comment: @user3386109: well a directed graph that is bidirectional without labeled edges would probably be isomorphic ( :p ) to an undirected graph? Since, well, if (a) points to (b), (b) points to (a), and since we do not distinguish between the edges, we can "join" the two :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, exactly. A circular doubly linked list is indeed equivalent to an undirected graph. From any node, you can traverse to either of two neighbors. And the nodes form a Hamiltonian cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each node `N` of the list, you just need to swap `N.next` and `N.prev`. After this, you change the reference of `head` to be the new `head.next`. If there is a `tail`, it should be updated to `tail.prev`.

Just for better visualization:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes; simply swap the `previous` and `next` pointers, as well as any `head` and `tail` pointers.  Can you explain how your friend claims that the list is symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

It is not impossible, it might require some extra care to design the algorithm, but that is with most (all) algorithms where you have to iterate and modify the data structure.

You can simply swap the `head` and `tail`, and then iterate over your linked list and swap the `next` and `previous` references for *each* node. You furthermore need to make sure you stop doing that after one full iteration.

A sample algorithm in Python would look like:

```
class CircularDoubleLinkedList:

    # ...

    def reverse(self):
        self.head, self.tail = self.tail, self.head
        start = cur = self.head
        if cur is not None:
            cur.next, cur.previous = cur.previous, cur.next
            cur = cur.previous
        while cur is not None and cur is not start:
            cur.next, cur.previous = cur.previous, cur.next
            cur = cur.previous  # move to the next node
```